# Not displaying the data given

Tags: php, mysql

The PHP file doesn't display any errors but it doesn't display the data it is ment to get from the MySQL database. It is not saying it can't connect to the databaseso I dont know how i broke it this time :(
      
    
    
        
      Search Engine

```
<body>
    <h2>Search Engine</h2>
    <form action='./search.php' method='get'>
        <input type='text' name='k' size='50' value='<?php echo $_GET['k'] ?>' />
        <input type='submit' value='Search'/>
    </form>
        <hr />
    <?php
        $k = $_GET['k'];
        $terms = explode(" ", $k);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE ";

        foreach ($terms as $each)
        {
            //....
        }

        //connect
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
        mysql_select_db("search");

        $query = mysql_query($query);

        $num_rows = 0;
        if ($query){
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                $id = $row['id'];
                $title = $row['title'];
                $description = $row['description'];
                $k = $row['Keywords'];
                $link = $row['link'];
                echo "<h2><a href='$link'>$title</a></h2>
                $description<br /><br />";
            }
        }
        else
            echo "No results found for \"<b>$k</b>\"";

        //disconnect
        mysql_close();

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And then I have the MySQL data base setup
[image: Database]

Comment: A suggestion, for greater readability change name variable to: 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE ";

Comment: Then: $query = mysql_query($sql);

Comment: **WARNING!** Your code contains an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) -- you are passing raw, unfiltered, unvalidated user input directly into an SQL string. Please [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli) so you can use [prepared statements with parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
$query = mysql_query($query);
```

to

```
$query = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

and see what happens

Comment: ok i got this in reply to what you said "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"

Comment: So you have an error somewhere. And if I am not mistaken, it appears as tho you are trying to bind based on the foreach statement. So you can do one of two things. Put the $sql query inside the foreach statement and run it that way, or you need to add a value to the WHERE clause. You only have WHERE. It should be more like WHERE search = ?. But don't take my word for it - it's 3:20am and Im tired. Should help you tho